# Does API Gateway edge-optimized cache any http response?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

It is written in the AWS doc that edge-optimized endpoints for API Gateway are using a managed Cloudfront distribution (to speed up accesses across the globe).

Since this is a "managed Cloudfront distribution", we cannot view the config of this Cloudfront distribution.

So my question is:

- what is the configuration of this managed Cloudfront distribution ?
- is this distribution configured to cache any content ?